# Is there any way to row reduce a matrix by taking the derivative of it?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I was wondering how computers might know how to row reduce a matrix, and it got me wondering that I've never took the derivative of a matrix before, but, a reduced row state seems a lot like it can be abstracted to a kind of minimum of a vector function. As such, I am wondering if a matrix can be optimized with any kind of vector calculus.

Comment: An interesting idea. There’s not really much to “know” in order to row-reduce a matrix, though. There’s an algorithm for doing that which can be followed blindly.

Comment: you do realize that peoples entire careers are built around "knowing" about numerical linear algebra and high performance computing

Comment: And you think that somehow means they're omnipotent? There's always new discoveries in math and niche formulas scattered around.